# Is there a utility that will eject external drives?

Tags: external-disk, eject

Is there a utility that will eject external drives?

I've tried force quitting the Finder (indexing was often the culprit), shutting down all open applications, but some process is still preventing the drive from ejecting.

Such a program would identify the offending process, shut it down and then eject the drive safely.

Comment: There's this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90573/unable-to-eject-or-erase-usb-drives, but I'm looking for a reliable utility.

Comment: `lsof` can identify processes which still access the disk (there should be a question on AD about this already).

Comment: I found a program, called Sloth: https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Sloth

Comment: Please don‘t add answers to the question directly, post them as answers to the linked question instead.